# Minimum computer specs for buying a used computer

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I tried to setup my laptop for school work to dual boot windows and linux only to nearly fuck it up due to windows 8 complicating everything, so I've decided not to take the risk and instead by a cheap used laptop.

maximum price is $80 (Im from Denmark, so please do not send me offers) so ofcause the laptop will not be great, but what is the minimum requirements for running linux
and ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207896/minimum-computer-specs-for-buying-a-used-computer/) by [Dynamitetalks](https://answers.ros.org/users/6157/dynamitetalks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The core ROS libraries will run on just about anything, particularly if it can run Ubuntu.

Which packages you want to use and what you want to do with your robot will have a much more significant impact on the CPU and memory requirements.

As suggested elsewhere (http://answers.ros.org/question/203712/to-buy-laptop-for-ros/ , http://answers.ros.org/question/61748/laptop-recommendations/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/52679/laptop-recommendation/ ), look for a laptop with an Nvidia graphics card.

Given your extremely limited budget, just buy the most powerful laptop you can, and hope it's enough.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0